# Excel formula to clean up stopwords

Tags: excel, stop-words

Would like your assistance with the following issue. I need to clean texts according to specific wordlist. Could not find specific formula (not VBA) to do that in Excel (being searching in other threads with no success) . THANK YOU
[image]

Comment: Since you cannot use VBA, you will need to use nested `SUBSTITUTE`'s.

Comment: Thank you for the general directions, i can understand the logic of substitute function, but  =SUBSTITUTE(A3, C2:C4, "") only will substitute "are" with nothing. How is the nested substitutes plays role here?

Comment: You have nest the substitutes.  Substitute will not accept an array.  So it would be something like `=substitute(substitute(substitute(a3,c2,""),c3,""),c4,"")`.  Gets pretty unwieldy with many names.

Comment: yes indeed, messy. So only VBA will work here?

Comment: Your choice -- messy formula vs VBA UDF -- to say nothing of the issue of words within words

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA UDF using Regular Expressions to replace all the StopWords in Text with nothing.  It handles the issue of partial word matches by using the word boundary token.  e.g If `you` is a stopword, it will replace `you` with nothing but will ignore `your`.  It will also replace any trailing spaces after the stopword with nothing.

---

```
Option Explicit
Function CleanStopWords(S As String, StopWords As Range)
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim SW() As String
    Dim C As Range
    Dim I As Long

ReDim SW(1 To StopWords.Count)
For I = 1 To StopWords.Count
    SW(I) = StopWords(I)
Next I

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True

    'create pattern using the StopWords
    .Pattern = "\b(?:" & Join(SW, "|") & ")\b\s*"

    CleanStopWords = .Replace(S, "")
End With

End Function
```

---